# how do i get values from datagrid?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, mxml

I have the following datagrid:

`<mx:DataGrid height="400" width="800" id="adverseEventDataGrid" borderColor="#000000" borderStyle="solid" draggableColumns="false" horizontalCenter="13" verticalCenter="0" verticalAlign="middle">
<mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="selectToys" dataField="selectToys" width="30" itemRenderer="mx.controls.CheckBox" rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selectedConcepts" textAlign="center"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="StudyId" dataField="StudyID" visible="false"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ConceptId" dataField="ConceptID" visible="true" width="40"/>
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>`

i need to get values when check box is selected in the datagrid. how do i get it ?

Comment: You might have to implement custom itemrenderer if you would like to specify a property other than 'selectedToys' to be the value that you would like to set on the checkbox. Or else, what ever you select on the checkbox will be binded back to the data of the data provider with your existing mxml. when user hits submit, check what you have in the Data provider(after selectign a couple of checkboxes) by debugging and let me know.

Comment: I'm new to flex. How to implement custom itemrenderer or how do i bind dataProvider values with mxml when checkbox as selected ?

Comment: You can check out the link here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html